# Running the Android Emulator on the same Windows PC as the Tizen Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I had Hyper-V enabled on windows 10 for android emulator and I just recently decided to try building a companion Tizen wearable app. To get Tizen working I had to disable Hyper-V. Of course Android emulator wants it (for reasonable performance).

I can't be the first to hit this? Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: From what I read the Tizen emulator can use HAXM. It may help to know what your PC specs are (Intel or AMD CPU, RAM available).

Comment: it's an Intel I9 from last year. Yeah I guess I didn't make this part clear. With hyper-v on for performant andriod use. The Tizen emulator was unusable. Now with hyper-v off and haxm installed andriod is unusable.

Comment: Okay weird HAXM with Android should be fine (heck that is recommended config). Side note: I would rebuild (delete/create) all Android emulators after any SDK updates in case something about the emulator code isn't compatible. Just in case, are you running the Android emulator and Tizen emulator at the same time?